# JavaFX element is null in the controller

Tags: java, javafx

I have an `ImageView imageview1`, in which I want to display an image loading from `resources` folder
But my imageview is null when I run the program

I saw lot of other posts saying that the problem was that people were initialising the ImageView again after FXML with something like `imageview1 = new ImageView();`, but I don't initialize it anywhere. If I try to initialise it in the start() then try to display the image, the program run fine but I don't see the image

Here is my controller's code :

```java
package com.morialog.moriamines.GUIs;

import com.morialog.moriamines.Partie.Item;
import com.morialog.moriamines.Utils;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainMenu extends Application {

    public static Stage primaryStage;
    public ImageView imageview1;

    public static void start() {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) {
        MainMenu.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        show();
        addImage( Item.IRON_SWORD );
        primaryStage.show();
        try {
            primaryStage.getIcons().add( new Image( String.valueOf( Utils.getResource( "/logo.png" ) ) ) );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( "Exception while loading the javaFX's icon" );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void show() {
        primaryStage.setTitle( "MoriaMines - Main menu" );
        primaryStage.setScene( Utils.getSceneFromRessource( GUI.MAIN_MENU ) );
    }

    public void addImage( Item item ) {
        try {
            Image img = new Image( getClass().getResource( "/Textures/" + item.toString() + ".png"
                                    ).toString() );
            imageview1.setImage( img );
        } catch( Exception a ) {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Solution by Slaw that fixed my problem :
You're using MainMenu as the fx:controller, then note you are ending up with two different instances of MainMenu. It's typically a bad idea to use your application class as a controller class as well

Comment: Why would it not be null? There’s no code anywhere in the question which would cause it to be initialized.

Comment: I think you're confusing the other posts you've read. If they were using FXML to define the `ImageView`, then you're correct, it should not be initialized by you in your code. Your example, however, is not using FXML so you must initialize the object in your code. And then actually, you know, add it to your Scene somewhere. :)

Comment: If you _are_ using FXML (if you are you should [edit] your question to provide a [mre]), and you're using `MainMenu` as the `fx:controller`, then note you are ending up with two different instances of `MainMenu`. It's typically a bad idea to use your application class as a controller class as well.

Comment: Sorry i completely forgot to precise that I'm using FXML file to load everything,
@Slaw answer fixed it, because I was using Application class as a controller too as he said. Thanks to all of you I will copy Slaw answer and mark it as the solution if he will not post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Slaw that fixed my problem :
You're using MainMenu as the fx:controller, then note you are ending up with two different instances of MainMenu. It's typically a bad idea to use your application class as a controller class as well

Comment: please edit your question to fit your answer :)